# Can't get accurate result for gsutil du command

Tags: google-cloud-storage

When I run the `gsutil du -sh` command in Google Cloud Storage to determine the size of a folder in my storage buckets it always returns 0 B.  I know this is incorrect but I can't understand why this is happening?  The command was working fine last week and all of the sudden stopped functioning properly. Anyone had this issue?

Comment: Can you still list the contents of the bucket with **gsutil**? Use **gsutil -D ...** to debug the problem.

Comment: I tried that I received a very long answer that it seems I cannot share here because of a character limit.  I don't really understand what it means.  I did use gsutil to list the contents of my bucket and that seemed to work accurately.

Comment: Try using https://pastebin.com/ to share output too long to include in stackoverflow.   Also, can you show the complete command, for example are you running `gsutil du -hs gs://bucket` or `gsutil du -hs gs://bucket/prefix/*` or plain old `gsutil du -sh` with no URL?

Comment: OK I will drop this here first.  Here is the actual command.
```gsutil du -sh gs://creative-us/SN\ Drive\ 01/Elements/Video/Boxing/Fighters/Joshua\ Anthony/Fights/```